# How to disable all FK in sqlServer

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have sqlServer db with many tables.

I want to upload some tables and make value changes but the foreign-keys are limit me.

I want to temporary disable all the FK and after I finish all me job , activate them

How can I do it?

Comment: Also see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/ ... but .... why can’t you just insert the data in parent tables first, and then child tables? Where is the data coming from? How can you trust that it will comply with your constraints when you re-enable them?

Answer (score 0):

Disable Constraint of all tables

```
 EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"
```

Enable Constraint of all tables

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"
```